# How can I make the active div move once another div is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

First off, I'm not an experienced programmer whatsoever. I mostly modify code and piece it together, so this is where I'm stuck.

I've created multiple div's to animate into location based on the link selected. When you click home, the logo should slide in from the right. When you click 'Vision' (another menu option) another div should slide in, WHICH it does. However, upon clicking the 'Vision' menu option, the 'Home' div containing the logo does not slide out.

I've somehow managed to do this before, but I'm unable to figure out how.

Here's the working example:

http://www.visiondigit.al

And here's my current project which I'm aiming to do the same process. I currently have an iFrame embed of a random link, but it serves purpose in terms of testing.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jzXM/

Here's the part of my code I've narrowed in on and tried messing around with

```
    jQuery(function($){
$('.fTab').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    })
```

If someone can help me out that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lost in your code... I did make you something much more simpler using CSS transition for animation and JQuery to trigger classes. It's just a shell, but you can build upon it exactly how you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/Lu6yx/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="first" class="toggles">First</li>
    <li id="second" class="toggles">Second</li>
</ul>
<div id="first-slide" class="panes"></div>
<div id="second-slide" class="panes"></div>
```

CSS

```
#first-slide {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9999px; /* get element out of viewport */
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#second-slide {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9999px; /* get element out of viewport */
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden; /* important to remove that side scroller */
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggles').click(function(){

        $('.panes').css('right', '-9999px'); // hide all tabs

        var elementID = $(this).attr('id'); // get the ID of the clicked element

        $('#'+elementID+'-slide').css('right', '0'); // show the desired element

    });
});
```